# Get last portion of URL with PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, I have the following string:

`$row_data[0] = "\Documents\Images\File";`

How do I extract the word `File` from this string with PHP?

I had tried this but it was unsuccessful.

`$end = substr(strrchr($row_data[0], '\'), 1);`

Comment: Why not explode() ?

Comment: I have found the solution. It should be `\\` and not just `\` :)

Comment: \ is a escape character so use double slash    $end = substr(strrchr($row_data[0], '\\'), 1);

Comment: it will help you, https://3v4l.org/1c7bq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\`

```
$row_data[0] = "\Documents\Images\File";
echo $end = substr(strrchr($row_data[0], '\\'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $end=end(explode("\\",$row_data[0]));
```

Comment: @devpro the escape character is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions, I think the one below is easiest, read about pathinfo()

```
$path   =   '\Documents\Images\File';
$lastPortion    =   pathinfo($path)['basename'];
```

Comment: How about:

 $path = '\Documents\Images\File';
 $lastPortion = array_reverse(explode('\\', $path))[0];
 echo $lastPortion;

You can also change '\\' with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Answer (score 0):

\ is a escape character so use double slash

```
<?php

 $row_data[0] = "\Documents\Images\File";
 $end = substr(strrchr($row_data[0], '\\'), 1);
                                     ^^^^^
 echo $end;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` will split string by `\` and
`array_pop()` gets last array's item

```
$lastItem= array_pop(explode('\\', $row_data[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

use double slash for escape character :

```
echo 'Hello World';

$row_data[0] = 'Documents\\Images\\File';


$end = substr(strrchr($row_data[0], '\\'), 1);

echo $end;
```